# How to add delay in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to add some delay time in my project with `time.sleep` at `def pin_popup_success(self):` but it make my program froze and not run `ACCESS GRANTED`. How to make program appear `ACCESS GRANTED` about 3 sec?

Code

```
def check_pin(self):
    if(self.input_code.get()!="1"):
        self.pin_popup_fail()
    else:
        self.pin_popup_success()

def pin_popup_fail(self):
    self.pinlabel.config(text="WRONG PIN")

def pin_popup_success(self):
    self.pinlabel.config(text="ACCESS GRANTED")
    self.returnToIdle_fromPin()
    time.sleep(3)
    
def returnToIdle_fromPin(self):
    self.pinFrame.pack_forget()
    self.show_idle()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
splash_root = Tk()
splash_root.after(3000,main_window)
```

it delays for 3 seconds then goto main_window Function